# What is the difference between necessary and sufficient conditions?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

- If $p\implies q$ ("$p$ implies $q$"), then $p$ is a **sufficient** condition for $q$.
- If $\lnot p\implies \lnot q$ ("not $p$ implies not $q$"), then $p$ is a **necessary** condition for $q$.

I don't understand what sufficient and necessary mean in this case. How do you know which one is necessary and which one is sufficient?

Comment: Those are the definitions of _necessary_ and of _sufficient_.

Comment: Are you aware that $\bar p \implies \bar q$ is the logical equivalent of $q \implies p$ ?  Do you know what "necessary" and "sufficient" mean in the English language?

Answer (score 34):

Suppose first that $p$ implies $q$. Then knowing that $p$ is true is **sufficient** (i.e., enough evidence) for you to conclude that $q$ is true. It’s possible that $q$ could be true even if $p$ weren’t, but having $p$ true ensures that $q$ is also true.

Now suppose that $\text{not-}p$ implies $\text{not-}q$. If you know that $p$ is false, i.e., that $\text{not-}p$ is true, then you know that $\text{not-}q$ is true, i.e., that $q$ is false. Thus, in order for $q$ to be true, $p$ **must** be true: without that, you automatically get that $q$ is false. In other words, in order for $q$ to be true, it’s **necessary** that $p$ be true; you can’t have $q$ true while $p$ is false.

Comment: As usual, I will point out that a downvote not accompanied by an explanatory comment is less than useful.

Comment: how do you know that p is true or not?

Comment: @cloud9resident: You don’t know. Whether $p$ is true or not is a completely separate issue from whether it is a necessary or sufficient condition for $q$. The latter does not depend in any way on the truth or falsity of $p$.

Comment: But for not p implies not q, in terms of that reasoning, not q doesn't tell you anything about not p because here are different paths to not q?

Comment: @committedandroider: That’s correct. Knowing that $\neg q$ is true tells you nothing about whether $\neg p$ is true or not.

Comment: So knowing q tells you it has to be p? I don't get what you mean by "without that, you automatially get that q is false"

Comment: @committedandroider: Yes, if you know that $\neg p\to\neg q$ and that $q$ is true, then $\neg p$ must be false, and therefore $p$ must be true. \\ If $p$ is not true, then $\neg p$ **is** true, and the implication $\neg p\to\neg q$ (which you are assuming) then automatically guarantees that $\neg q$ is true and hence that $q$ is false.

Comment: And that logic would work with p->q as well because if you know that q is false, then p must be false as well because you're saying p is a sufficient path to q?

Comment: @committedandroider: That’s right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott One question.Let $f$ be a function defined on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$. Then we know a _necessary and sufficient condition_ for Riemann integrable of $f$(say this condition as $Q$) is $f$ _is continuous almost everywhere_ (say this condition as $P$).
As you have written that if $P\implies Q$ then $P$ is sufficient condition of $Q$ and _$Q$ could be TRUE even $P$ were not true_. So there exists an example of a function which is not continuous a.e. but still Riemann integrable. What is that example ?

Comment: "...but having p true ensures that q is also true."  And yet the truth table has an entry for P is true and Q is false.  The sheer quantity of writing to convince someone why P⟹Q is true or false is amazing.  Something obviously is wrong.  Since the math of the logic is correct, it must be the explanations that are at fault.  If there was as much verbiage surrounding 1+1=2, we'd still be counting on our fingers!

Comment: @Empty: (For some reason I never saw this comment.) When I say that $Q$ could be true even if $P$ is false, I am not saying that such an example must necessarily exist: I am saying that such an example is consistent with $P\to Q$. Obviously if $P$ is a necessary **and sufficient** condition for $Q$, then $P\leftrightarrow Q$, and no such example can exist.

Comment: @user756686: Any truth table for a proposition involving variables $p$ and $q$ will have a line for $p$ true and $q$ false: that’s simply a fact about the structure of truth tables. It will also have lines for $p$ and $q$ both true, $p$ and $q$ both false, and $p$ false and $q$ true. What is relevant here is that the entry in the column for $p\to q$ in the line $p$ true and $q$ false is F: when $p$ is true and $q$ is false, the implication $p\to q$ is false. There is no problem here whatsoever.

Answer (score 24):

I always think of it in terms of sets.

[image]

In the picture above, for an element to be purple, it's necessary to be red, but it is not sufficient.

The same holds for the blue set, to be in the blue set is a necessary condition in order to be purple, but it is not enough, it's not sufficient.

A sufficient condition is stronger than a necessary condition. If you tell me that you have a red or blue element I can't say for sure if it is in the purple set, but if you tell me that you have a purple element I now for sure that it is in the red and blue sets.

Comment: But purple is neither red nor blue…

Comment: Yes, and this comment is an edit to change "have a purple element" to "have an element from the purple area.  I am so happy to read something that does not use the word imply.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It has always been difficult for me to connect the linguistic sense of the terms "necessary" and "sufficient" with mathematics.  However, with practice with the following table, this skill becomes automatic.

[image]

I'm assuming you understand the meaning of the implication.  In any case it is helpfull to think about simple example when looking at this table. For example: "If it is raining, then close the window". Then it remains to understand the following.

**P is a sufficient for Q.** If P is true then Q will be always true (the first line in the table). *Note that we do not consider the second line.* But as we see in the table Q can be true also when P is false (the third line in the table). So P is "just" a sufficient condition for Q.

**Q is a necessary condition for P.** It is obvious from the table. P can be true "only" when Q is true (the first line in the table). *Note that we do not consider the second line.*

**About $\lnot A \implies \lnot B$.** It is called the contrapositive of the statement $A\implies B$. As you see it is not necessary for you for understanding the "sufficiency" and "necessaty".

Comment: I think you probably meant that `~A => ~B` is the contrapositive of `B => A`.