# How to determine sufficient and necessary conditions?

Tags: logic

Which of the following conditions are

a) necessary , b) sufficient for the natural number $n$ to be divisible by $6$?

(i) $n$ is divisible by $3$

(ii) $n$ is divisible by $9$

(iii) $n$ is divided by $12$

(iv) $n$ is even and divisible by $3$

(v) $n=132$

please tell me how you were able to solve it?

Comment: Many people here think that the use of allcaps is the same as shouting...please edit your post.  As to your question...you must have some idea.  What about the fifth one?  $n=132$ .  Is that sufficient?  Is it necessary?

Comment: See the post [What is the difference between necessary and sufficient conditions ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256171/what-is-the-difference-between-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions)

Comment: "if $A$, then $B$" must be read : "$A$ is  a *sufficient* condition for $B$" and "$B$ is a *necessary* condition for $A$".

Comment: The first step in solving these problems should be to look up the definitions of "sufficient" and "necessary"1

Comment: And intuition must help : $3$ divides $15$ but $6$ does not. This means that to be divisible by $3$ is **not** sufficient in order to be divisible by $6$. But if a number is divisible by $6$ it is obviously divisible also by $3$. This means that divisibility by $3$ is *necessary* for the divisibility by $6$.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in solving these problems should be to look up the definitions of "sufficient" and "necessary"!  Condition "A" is "sufficient" for condition B if knowing that A is true immediately tells us that B is true.  Knowing that "n is divisible by 3" does NOT immediately tell us that "n is divisible by 6" (9 is divisible by 3 but not by 6) so "divisible by 3" is NOT "sufficient" for "divisible by 6".  Condition "A" is "necessary" for condition "B" if knowing that A is false immediately tells us that B is false.  Knowing that n is NOT divisible by 3 does tell us immediately that n is not divisible by 6 so "divisible by 3" **is** a necessary condition for "division by 6"