# X's-being-a-necessary-condition-for-Y is both a necessary and a sufficient condition for Y's-being-a-sufficient-condition-for-X.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

**X's-being-a-necessary-condition-for-Y is both a necessary and a sufficient condition for Y's-being-a-sufficient-condition-for-X.**

I am unable to come up with proof for the above statement. I know it's true, but I am unable to figure out how.

Following is my approach:
X being a necessary condition for Y means that Y *implies* X,

**To prove:** Y->X is both a necessary and sufficient condition for Y's being a sufficient condition for X.

Now we can write *Y's being a sufficient condition for X* as Y -> X.
So can we say that Y->X is a necessary and sufficient condition for Y->X

I am not sure how to proceed. Kindly help.

Comment: I think you are done since you observed that X necessary for Y, and Y sufficient for X are the exact same implication.

Comment: See the post [What is the difference between necessary and sufficient conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256171/what-is-the-difference-between-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions)

Comment: Correct: the convoluted statement of the problem amounts to: $(Y \to X) \leftrightarrow (Y \to X)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks.

Comment: @paw88789 Can I also prove this by contradiction? How can I proceed with a proof by contradiction? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4492233/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51704/5038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72970413/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).